# Testing spring boot api with database

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want auto testing my spring api. Now I have about 7-8 interesting situation and make:

1. deploy in postgres 7 db (test1, 2, ....)
2. application.properties write db test1.
3. run test and go to 2.

This is hard. What is easy way?

1. I want have one db for test (clear db, only tables structure)
2. before test write in db fixtures (special file with data, example - users, reports and other)
3. run test
4. after test delete fixture and have clear db again.

Can I do it by spring? Early I programming in python/django and use like way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to solve that would be via custom properties files and @Configuration classes.

You would create for each Test the property file e.g. *test1-dbA.properties*

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
jdbc.username=db1
jdbc.password=..
```

Next you would define the DataSource bean that loads the properties from the *test1-dbA.properties*

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.baeldung.repository")
@PropertySource("test1-dbA.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DB1Config {
        @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }
// ...
}
```

In the JUnit Test you would load the configuration class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, DB1Config.class})
public class db1Test{
    // ...
}
```

This and other options can be looked up here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database

Comment: To add to the above, use profiles to easily set what properties to use for your tests. If you are using spring boot and set the correct spring data jpa properties (spring.jpa), you don't need to create your own DataSource bean

Comment: Thank you. Have special configuration for test with @SpringBootTest very good idea. But I want more. In django I do (example):

1. In prod database I find interesting user and make fixture for it (it is special json file with user and join entity):  manage.py dumpdata users > fixtures/user.json
2. Before test I load fixture (in code) fixtures = ['user.json',....]
3. After test framework delete fixture (by transaction) himself.

Your way is good, but I must make db for test by hand (sql scripts), have not fixture file.

Comment: I work with this idea and find algoritm: 

    1. I use spring boot and annotation TestPropertySource for use special entry DB.
    2. use annotation sql for add fixture in DB
    3. and annotation sql for clear DB
My fixture is sql command in file. Eamon Scullion, thank you.